# Javascript oops: defining function with or witout prototype

Tags: javascript, oop

Below is my class:

```
function myfunc(){
    // some code
}
```

1) declaring a method/function of a class

```
myfunc.getInstance = function(){
          // some code
};
```

Or alternatively i can define like below:

```
myfunc.prototype.getInstance = function(){
    // some code
};
```

Please tell me what is the difference between defining method/function with or without prototype.

Comment: The first option is almost never a good idea. Use the prototype. JS is very forgiving, you could do `var a=[]; a.func=function(){}` but that doesn't mean you should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prototype functions are meant to be called on an object of class (like a normal class in OOPs). Where as normal functions can be called directly on the class (like a static class in OOPs).

```
function Foo ()
{
}

//Should be called through Foo.SayHello()
Foo.SayHello = function ()
{

}


/*
Should be called on the object of Foo
var MyObject = new Foo();
MyObject.SayHello();
*/

Foo.prototype.SayHello = function ()
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

with

`myfunc.prototype.getInstance = function(){
    // some code
};`

if you create any object that inherits myfunc, it will be able to access getInstance method with prototype chain. the new object's __ proto __ will point to prototype of its parent i.e myfunc's

with

```
myfunc.getInstance = function(){
      // some code};
```

getInstance method cannot be inherited and hence only myfunc is able to call it not the objects which inherits it.

example

```
function myfunc(){

}

myfunc.getInstance = function(){
    console.log("I can be invoked only by myfunc")
}

myfunc.prototype.getInstance2 = function(){
    console.log("I can be inherited and called by other objects too")
}

let newobj = new myfunc();

newobj.getInstance2();

// I can be inherited and called by other objects too


newobj.getInstance();
// Uncaught TypeError: newobj.getInstance is not a function

myfunc.getInstance();
// I can be invoked only by myfunc
```